# Selectively load a certain font

Tags: fonts, pdftex

I'm using pdflatex, and I would like to load a specific font from a package. For example, I only want to use the `mathfrak`, `mathcal`, and `mathscr` fonts of `stickstoo` from `newtxmath` (but nothing else). The whole package could be loaded via

```
\usepackage[stickstoo,vvarbb]{newtxmath}
```

but that would load many other things and not just those fonts.

Previously, I've done something similar: load Euler caligraphic font via the command

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\eur}{U}{zeus}{m}{n}
\newcommand{\matheur}[1]{\eur{#1}}
```

I found it somewhere on the internet and just copied and pasted. Now, the sequence

```
{U}{zeus}{m}{n}
```

looks completely mysterious to me. So I would like to ask:

- In particular, how to achieve the goal above (selectively use those fonts from `newtxmath`)?
- More generally, how do I figure out what to put in `\DeclareMathAlphabet` myself?

Thanks!

Comment: `{U}{zeus}{m}{n}` is a New Font Selection Scheme code for: Unspecified encoding, virtual-Euler-Script family, medium weight, normal shape. If you want to load Euler Script, though, load it through either `mathalfa`or the traditional `eucal`/`euscript` packages instead. Much simpler. Better yet, Neo Euler is available for `unicode-math`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PDFLaTeX, Use the [`mathalfa`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathalfa/doc/mathalfa.pdf) package to select individual script alphabets.  For example

```
\usepackage[cal=txupr ,
            frak=pxtx ,
            scr=pxtx
           ]{mathalfa}
```

This assumes you want the TX upright alphabet as `\mathcal`.  If these fonts aren’t the right height to match your math font, also provide `calscaled=`, `frakscaled=` and `scrscaled=`. package options.

Euler Script is available through the `mathalfa` package as well.  If you don’t want to use `mathalfa`, I would recommend loading those alphabets through the traditional packages`eucal`, `euscript` and `eufrak`, which are part of `amsfonts`.  (Note that `euscript` and `eucal` make the same Euler Script alphabet available as `\mathscr` or `\mathcal`, respectively.)  The OpenType version compatible with `unicode-math` is Neo Euler.

A PDFTeX-compatible way to select the more conventional math alphabets (such as upright, italic and bold) is `isomath`.

With the modern toolchain, Asana Math provides math alphabets based on Young Ryu’s `px` fonts.  (It also contains an different script alphabet as a stylistic alternate, so you can have both `\mathcal` and `\mathscr`.)  TeX Gyre Termes Math is also reasonably similar to `newtx`.  With `unicode-math`, you can give either an option such as

```
\setmathfont[Scale = MatchUppercase, range={cal, bfcal, frak, bffrak}]{Asana Math}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer. One question I still have is that how do I figure out those names txupr, pxtx? For example, if I want to load shapes from stickstoo in newtxmath, how do I know what the name is?

Comment: And unfortunately, I cannot use unicode-math since I can only use pdflatex.

Comment: @QcH It’s in the documentation that I linked, along with font samples.

Comment: Thanks! I've looked at the documentation you linked and it seems like it only has fonts from esstix rather than stickstoo/stix 2. Also, I want to know, in general, is it possible to figure out how to manually load some symbols from a certain font like for Euler example I gave above.

Comment: Yes: see the font tables in the [`stix2-type1` manual](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/fonts/stix2-type1/stix2.pdf#subsection.6.2) and use `\DeclareMathAlphabet`.. Or find the relevant lines in the `*.sty` file and copy-and-paste. Or load `stix2` first and then your preferred font package over it (if that won’t make you run out of math alphabets).

Comment: That's closer to what's I'm looking for. Though, as I'm pretty new to this, how do I actually make it work? For example, if I look at http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/fonts/stix2-type1/stix2.pdf#section.4, does it give me any info on how to load this font in some range?

Comment: @QcH The page you link discusses Unicode ranges and is relevant to the Unicode version of the font, `STIX2Math.otf`. In `unicode-math`, you would use the `[range=...]` option of `setmathfont`, probably with an alias such as `cal` or `frak`.

Comment: @QcH The specific commands in the case of `stix2.sty` are actually a little hard to guess, because the package packs a lot of different gylphs into the limited number of legacy NFSS math alphabets, declares a local symbol encoding, and repurposes the weights and shapes as additional symbol alphabets. You can open the `stix2.sty` file from your TeX directory to see the exact commands it uses for that.

Comment: @QcH If you want to post a separate question about STIX Two, I’ll answer it when I get the chance.